# android - add actionbarsherlock to project already refer to appcompat_v7

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

I create project refer to appcompat_v7 then I want add action bar shelock library I find many error

This one From what I got :

> [2014-11-17 10:46:16 - HoroScop]
>   C:\Users\Pc\apps\appcompat_v7\res\values\attrs.xml:32: error:
>   Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined

my tries :

1-  clean build many times

2- delete all support library v.4 and add it from android tools to get last version in the library and my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use AppCompat and ActionBarSherlock together because they are using the attributes/resources.
By the way, with android 21, you should use the AppCompat.

Comment: So if i want use actionbar i should use AppCompat one Right ?

Comment: Yes, and even better if you choose to use the new Toolbar inside the appCompat lib.